# Need razor view engine auto-complete to work in a class library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, autocomplete, intellisense

We have a modular architecture where we have some views (cshtml) files in a separate project (class library).  How can we get the <del>syntax highlighting and</del> autocomplete to work when the project isn't an MVC project?

Please note that the class library has controllers, views, models etc.  It just doesn't have the web.config, global.asax, etc that a normal mvc project would have.

The intellisense works for everything but the so important model:
[image: screenshot of model error]

With MVC3 RTM, if you hover over the Model, you can now get a better error message:

> C:\...\Index.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime
>   error: There is no build provider
>   registered for the extension
>   '.cshtml'. You can register one in the
>   <compilation><buildProviders>
>   section in the machine.config or
>   web.config.  Make sure is has a
>   BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute
>   attribute which includes the value
>   'Web' or 'All'.

So I added this:

```
<compilation>
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </assemblies>
    <buildProviders>
      <add
         extension=".cshtml"
         type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
```

Then after adding the build provider, this error message appears:

> C:\...\Index.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime
>   error: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>   (C:\...\machine.config line 259)

Comment: have you checked the open with dialog to make sure it uses Razor Editor? I created a console app, added a cshtml file and syntax highlighting works. Intellisense doesn't seem to work with local class files though but it does seem to work with global references like `system.`

Comment: Same problem.
Placing Web.config in View directory (copy from any new MVC3 RC project) also helps. But it is not 100%. IntelliSence cant see my custom types.

Comment: Yea, syntax highlighting works, but intellisense doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I played around for a bit and found that if you want to access any local objects (classes within your library) They must be set to public for Intellisense to show up. Give this a shot and see if that works. Otherwise a default ClassLibrary has intellisense it seems.

Comment: There is now a better error message provided with the MVC3 RTM product.  I've added it above.

Comment: i installed MVC3 and a Resharper update today and suddently i have Razor intellisense.

Comment: I had a similar problem, I solved it by making sure my project referenced `Microsoft.CSharp`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The webconfig from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/01/20/how-to-get-razor-intellisense-for-model-in-a-class-library-project.aspx) will work. I've copied it below (for posterity):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>

    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Make sure you add it at the root of your project and it will work even without all of those assemblies referenced.

Comment: This worked well, thanks.  Perhaps this is obvious, but after a little trial and error I realized that the config must be named Web.config, not App.config

Comment: This config allows the `@model` directive to be recognized (`@ModelType` in VB.Net) but the next problem I run into is that `@Html` doesn't resolve to `WebViewPage(Of TModel).Html As System.Web.HtmlHelper(Of TModel)`, but instead makes an ambiguous reference to `System.Web.Mvc.Html` and `System.Web.WebPages.Html` in VB.Net.

Answer (score 12):

For Visual Studio 2012/ASP.NET MVC 4, you need to update the assembly versions and add `<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />` to `appSettings`. Here's what my Web.config looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. I believe the difference was the assemblies under the system.web.compilation element.

Answer (score 6):

I have followed Jammer's suggestion and am documenting what I believe is the minimal set of actions to get a project suitable for serving as an ASP.NET MVC4 class library project. This was done in Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, and was targeting VB.Net. I may later include documentation for doing something similar in Visual Studio 2013 if I get a chance. Here are the actions I took:

1. Create a new blank MVC4 project with a separate directory for the solution (so you can clearly see that the `packages` directory with updated versions of reference files is part of the project).
2. Add a dummy controller, view and model to test it (which entailed copying the output DLL and view to another web application after building the class library).
3. Delete the following files from the project:

   - The whole `App_Start` folder
   - The whole `App_Data` folder and any other empty folders (my Mercurial history didn't make this visible so I'm going from memory).
   - `Global.asax`
   - `Global.asax.vb`
   - The `Web.config` file in the root and the dependent `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config` files. (Do **not** delete `Web.config` from the Views folder.)
4. Delete the following sections from the `Web.config` file in the Views folder:

   - `appSettings`
   - `system.web`
   - `system.webServer`
   - You may also delete lines `<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />` and `<add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />`
5. Remove the following references from the project (* starred references were version-specific references that went into the `packages` directory and have `Copy Local` and `Specific Version` set to `True`).

   - `System.Web.Entity`
   - `System.Web.ApplicationServices`
   - `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`
   - `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`
   - `System.Web.Extensions`
   - `System.Web.Extensions.Design`
   - `System.Xml.Linq`
   - `System.Web.Abstractions`
   - `System.Web.Routing`
   - `System.Configuration`
   - `System.Web.Services`
   - `System.EnterpriseServices`
   - `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` (1.0.0.0) *
   - `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes` (1.0.0) *
   - `Newtonsoft.Json` (4.5.11) *
   - `System.Net.Http` (2.0.20710.0) *
   - `System.Net.Http.Formatting` (4.0.20710.0) *
   - `System.Net.Http.WebRequest` (2.0.20710.0) *
   - `System.Web.Helpers` (2.0.20710.0) *
   - `System.Web.Http` (4.0.20710.0) *
   - `System.Web.Http.WebHost` (4.0.20710.0) *
6. Remove the following project-wide Imports from the project settings:

   - `System.Xml.Linq`
   - `System.Collections.Specialized`
   - `System.Configuration`
   - `System.Web.Caching`
   - `System.Web.Mvc.Ajax`
   - `System.Web.Routing`
   - `System.Web.SessionState`
   - `System.Web.Security`
   - `System.Web.Profile`
   - `System.Web.UI`
   - `System.Web.UI.WebControls`
   - `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts`
   - `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`
7. Remove the following from `packages.config`:

   - <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
   - <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
   - <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
   - <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
   - <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
   - <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
   - <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
   - <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net40" />
8. Delete the following sub-directories from the packages folder:

   - Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.1.0.0
   - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.4.0.20710.0
   - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.20710.0
   - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0
   - Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.4.0.20710.0
   - Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0
   - Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0
   - Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.11

This leaves me with the following:

1. A VB.Net class library project targeting .NET Framework 4 (although I had intended this to be 4.5 - I think either works).
2. The following non-default .NET references (starred references must have `Copy Local` and `Specific Version` set to `True`):

   - System.Web
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll *
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.20715.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll *
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll *
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll *
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll *
3. The following non-default imports:

   - System.Web
   - System.Web.Mvc
   - System.Web.Mvc.Html
4. The following project files/structure:

   - `Controllers` folder containing `CustomUIController.vb`
   - `Models` folder containing `CustomUIModel.vb`
   - `Views` folder containing `CustomUI` folder, containing `Index.vbhtml`
5. `Web.config` file in the Views folder. See below for content.
6. `packages.config` file in the root of the project. See below for content.

The contents of my files are as follows:

### Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

</configuration>
```

### packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20715.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

### CustomUIController.vb

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Public Class CustomUIController
   Inherits Controller

   Public Function Index() As ActionResult
      Return View()
   End Function
End Class
```

### CustomUIModel.vb

```
Public Class CustomUIModel
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property Value As Decimal
End Class
```

### Index.vbhtml

```
@ModelType CustomTemplate.CustomUIModel

@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Name)
```

At this point I am able to work with Intellisense assisting me in the .vbhtml views and the .vb classes, build the project, then copy just the views to the primary application's deployed `Views` folder (in the appropriate sub-directory), and the project's primary output DLL to the primary application's deployed `bin` directory (the dependent DLL files are already there).

**Edit:**

After following the process on another system to validate it and how it works for .NET 4.5 and VS 2013, I have noticed the following:

1. I think I neglected to mention that the reference to `System.Web.DynamicData` can be removed.
2. In VS 2013 and/or .NET 4.5, some versions change:

   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
   - packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
3. I don't know if I made a strong enough point of it above, but the references to private (Copy Local) DLLs *do* have to be set to Copy Local, and/or *do* have to use the version provided in the packages folder when creating a project from the MVC4 template. I don't know why, but the .NET standard versions (non-private) don't seem to work, as far as Intellisense is concerned at least.
4. Best way to check if things are still "OK" as far as the IDE is concerned is to close the solution, delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in the custom project's output, re-load the solution, put the cursor on `LabelFor` in the Index.vbhtml file, and press the F12 key to see if it takes you to the Object Browser.

Because of the new versions, the packages file is different:

### Packages.config

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 4):

Alright, this is a longshot, but I ran across the same problem.  Are you using JetBrains Resharper?

Resharper overrides VS's intellisense engine but it doesn't understand Razor syntax.  You simply have to tell VS to rely on its own intellisense rather than Resharper's.

In VS2010, go Resharper - Options - Intellisense - General.  Then check the Visual Studio radio button.

Worked great for me.

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions I could find online or on SO fixed this for me.

May seem like a sledgehammer to crack a nut but I created an MVC 4 application project instead of a class library and ripped out everything I didn't need.  Intellisense and `@model` working fine.