# Razor Compiler Warning/Errors - ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, compiler-errors, asp.net-mvc-4, compiler-warnings

I have an issue which seems to have been reported here:

[Need razor view engine auto-complete to work in a class library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158573/need-razor-view-engine-auto-complete-to-work-in-a-class-library)

My issue is the following Warning:

> G:\Accountable\Accountable\Views\LedgerUser\EditorTemplates\LedgerServiceViewModel.cshtml:
>   ASP.NET runtime error: There is no build provider registered for the
>   extension '.cshtml'. You can register one in the
>    section in machine.config or web.config.
>   Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which
>   includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

This issue is apparent in all my views. Sample images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now all posts and references online that I have found are referencing to adding various Web.config (as mentioned in the previous post) options, but this doesn't seem to work, as I have these configurations defaulted in the project. Here are my Web Configs:

[Main Web.config](http://pastebin.com/9uCEFsQS)

[View root Web Config](http://pastebin.com/8yz4gJYv)

I think this issue maybe while im also getting the following compiler errors on the Views:

> The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Almost duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158573/need-razor-view-engine-auto-complete-to-work-in-a-class-library

Comment: Hey David. Thanks for the comment. Yes i referenced that in the post above. I cannot see any difference with the default ones created in the Project.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Arrrgghhh i had missed the following from the ROOT Web.config:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <!-- New -->
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

This allowed fixed the error and allowed me to use Intellisense within the View.

Comment: I don't really know why this fixed it, but it did.  It was working fine and then I reversed a very small hunk on a file in git and my whole project blew up.  This seemed to fix it.

Comment: This worked for mvc5, just change the version to `3.0.0.0` and the public key to the one in your web.config (it's at the end of the file).

Comment: in MVC 5 updated all versions and keys but the error is still here.

Answer (score 3):

Putting back the following lines in root Web.config fixed:

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by simply unloading and reloading the project. All the namespaces above were already there in the root web.config and I was still getting this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the temporary asp.net framework files works for me.

Stop IIS and remove everything under this folder:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[framework version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Then restart IIS. Bam!

Comment: Starting receiving this error for no apparent reason - my project was working for years previously. This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried by restart IIS, removed Temporary ASP.NET Files and changing the compilation tag in the web config file. None of them work for me.

I fixed the issue by removing and adding System.Web.MVC to the project.

In my case Razor syntax are Highlighted in red.