# Runtime error there is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get the following error when I try to run one of my scaffolded views in mvc 4:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'. You can register one in the  section in
>   machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a
>   BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value
>   'Web' or 'All'.

The only answers I have found relate to intellisense but my code complies fine and breaks at runtime.  This is a strange error as I am not using a class library.  There is just one controller that gives this message on all of its views, all other controllers/views work fine.

Comment: check this previous question which seems to have the solution:
[cshtml errors][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769926/razor-compiler-warning-errors-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Sort of, I tired playing around with this sort of thing at the time but ended up just recreating the views in question.  So never found a solution really.

Comment: I received this error in accordance with a typical build error I get when strong typing the views. The fix for that is just manually delete bin and obj and resolving that issue resolved this one for me.

Comment: After closing solution and reopen again, solve the problem

Answer (score 67):

This solved the problem for me.

Change this in `Web.config`

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" optimizeCompilations="true" />
```

to

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" optimizeCompilations="false" />
```

ADDED: when after a few minutes I back web.config to old, the problem not repeated. strange things )

Comment: This is probably because optimizeCompilations="true" leads to only *changed* files being compiled.

If there's something wrong with a previous compilation it won't be fixed unless the offending file(s) are recompiled, which won't happen until they are changed.

Setting optimizeCompilations="false" will cause everything to be recompiled, regardless of change state. Once your site is working again you can switch back to "true".

Comment: This exactly happens in my case. Once I change the optimizeCompilations to false or even get rid of the optimizeCompilations and rebuild the solution it fix. And then you can put it back. It just force recompiled everything. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any option or setting in IIS to to that with a click?

Comment: Marek, I changed the target version of .NET which had the same affect.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 16):

If the solution in [Razor Compiler Warning/Errors - ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769926/razor-compiler-warning-errors-asp-net-mvc-4) did not work by adding the following code to the ROOT web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <!-- New -->
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

then try restarting Visual Studio.  This worked for me, so would suggest that perhaps a Visual Studio bug.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio worked for me. Even though my Web.Config only has these:  System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Abstractions, System.Web.Routing, System.Data.Linq, System.Data.Entity, System.Data.Entity.Design     and does not have: System.Web.Helpers, System.Web.WebPages

Comment: This worked for me and still worked once I removed the above from the web.config. Not sure what caused the error in the first place.

Comment: Worked for me too, but be sure you use the same versions here that you use in your actual references in your project.

Comment: Restarting visual studio worked for me. It looks like not all of the dll's in my solution were regenerating, so the errors were actually file not found...

Answer (score 4):

I got this error on deployment (of a previously working site) after updating to VS2013 RC2. Luckily I had other sites to compare the bin folder to - it turns out several libraries were previously deploying and *magically* stopped, including the razor libraries. I changed their references `Copy Local` properties to `True` and it was all better. The 3 razor libraries in question were:

- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor

I also lost the libraries whose namespaces are referenced in the web.config file, so be sure to set those to copy local as well.

I suspect it may be possible to resolve this on the server using the GAC, but I don't know a lot about the server side of things, so that is for another time.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed a similar issue - documented here: https://naa4e.codeplex.com/workitem/1

The solution was that I deleted references and re-added NuGet packages.

The issue seems to be that the project originally referenced MVC4 which I guess was located somewhere on the local machine (i.e. was not a NuGet Package). I simply 'restored' the package which did not properly overwrite the project reference from 4 to 5.

Comment: Note: I realise my answer refers to a fix for MVC5 rather than 4 but hopefully suggests another avenue to try.

Answer (score 3):

Click 'Rebuild Solution' is enough to me

Comment: But not enough for me, I tried @DrakonHash way and that is worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by changing the .Net Framework from my current version "4.52" to "4.6".
You can change this if you right click on your project -> Properties then
"Target Framework"
 After changing the current Framework, I rebuild and everything worked fine.

After this I switched back to my current Framework version and it now works.
I really don't understand why this occurs but that helped for me.

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be related to the JIT-compiler in ASP.Net. We just had this error on a productive server after we changed a single .cshtml file at runtime and didn't get the application to work again. Restarting the web-application and recycle IIS Application Pool didn't help.

Just for testing I changed the `targetFramework="4.0"` to another version and it immediately worked again. After I changed it back to the initial version-number it also worked again. I guess this change causes a complete rebuild of any Asp.Net Temporary files.

[dnn](/questions/tagged/dnn) [2sxc](/questions/tagged/2sxc)

Answer (score 1):

I tried by restart IIS, removed Temporary Internet Files and changing the compilation tag in the web config file. None of them work for me.

I fixed the issue by removing and adding System.Web.MVC to the project.