# Razor page does not work after adding MVC to WebForms project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

I added MVC to my existing Web Forms project, but then when I try to add MVC razor page I got this rutime error:

```
There is no build provider registered for the extension '.cshtml'. You can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.
```

Answer to similar question [Razor Compiler Warning/Errors - ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769926/razor-compiler-warning-errors-asp-net-mvc-4) gave me a hint, so I fixed that run-time crash by modifying root Web.Config.
I added to  element this code:

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</assemblies>
```

That helped.

Then I removed that "assemblies" configuration, but my web project kept working.

Why razor crashed initially and why does it work now?

Update:
I noticed that this error happened on Windows 7 computers, but did not happen on Windows 8 computers.