# c# Razor Editor Autocomplete

Tags: c#, razor, autocomplete, editor

I'm trying to build my own Razor Editor. When the user inputs a "." after a variable a dropdown with the corresponding sup-properties should appear.

I'm working with the System.Web.Razor namespace. But was not able to find a solution for my task. The documention of this library is really bad....

Any Help would be nice.

Thx in advance
David

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another stackoverflow post could help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753215/1559355

I think it has to do with the way VS reads your project type, 
so if you don't use VS2013, upgrading to it might be a quick solution.

Comment: I'm trying to build my own Editor. I need a editor for creating templates inside the application i create. Our Customers won't have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: then maybe it's time to be rhetoric and explain them the money/time/correctness implications of authoring an in-house tool.