# Visual Studio Pro 2013 - Intellisense only works on pages with code-behind

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I've installed Visual Studio Pro 2013.  No complaints except that intellisense won't work on pages that have .Net code.  If I have a page with a separate code-behind page, then no problem.  I have tried deleting the solution file, reboot VS 2013.  I've tried a number of different projects and it's the same.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was fixed by resetting user settings.
Try to reset user settings win+r devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Comment: Seems to be a more prevalent problem.  I still haven't been able to solve it.  Some think it's a deliberate feature of the latest VS

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561779/vs2015-intellisense-not-working-in-razor-views-in-a-class-library It helped me last time then I had such issues.